# How do i clear a datepicker with VBA in Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

i am trying to write some code to clear a template. I have run into a problem when i try to clear a date picker. The code i have now does clear the datepicker, but it also removes the date picker function. Code is included below, thanks in advance!

```
Dim StopDate As ContentControl
Dim StartDate As ContentControl

With ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1)
  .Type = wdContentControlText
  .Range.Text = ""
  .Type = wdContentControlDropdownList
End With

With ActiveDocument.ContentControls(2)
  .Type = wdContentControlText
  .Range.Text = ""
  .Type = wdContentControlDropdownList
End With
```

Comment: The code you provide declares two content controls as type wdContentControlText, clears them by writing a null string to the .Text property of the content control, and then changes the type of the content control to type wdContentControlDropDownList.  Did you intent to change the type of the content control.  There is also no apparent link between the ActiveDocument.ContentControls 1 & 2 and the content controls you declare as StartDate and StopDate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working with Date content controls, you should use wdContentControlDate. For example:

```
With ActiveDocument
  With .ContentControls(1)
    .Type = wdContentControlText
    .Range.Text = ""
    .Type = wdContentControlDate
  End With

  With .ContentControls(2)
    .Type = wdContentControlText
    .Range.Text = ""
    .Type = wdContentControlDate
  End With
End With
```